# Xcode builds successfully but doesn't run

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I tried both Xcode 4 and Xcode 5 to build and run my projects. Previously they work fine but suddenly they just stop running/updating the simulator and device despite showing build success. I tried searching for solutions over here but none of them worked for me.

I've checked at the Edit Scheme page, at the Build tab on the left panel, among Analyze, Test, Run, Profile and Archive, Run and Profile were greyed out. Is this the cause of it?

Comment: Anyone please? This problem extends to all my projects, including the Hello World test projects.

Answer (score 0):

I would try what Nitin said above, and also clear the derived data. You can do this by:

- Opening the organizer (in the window menu)
- Going to the projects tab
- Clicking delete by derived data on your project